# Why is my C program printing a rubbish value?

Tags: c

In the program below, I am not getting the correct answers.
If I enter "1" as an input for `scanf`, the result `-4200052` will be printed.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int n;
int a = -n-4;
int square = n*n;
int b = square-7;

printf("ENTER AN INTEGER: ");
scanf ("%d" , &n);

if (n<3)
printf ("%d" , a);

else
{
   if (n >= 3 || n <= 10)
   printf ("%d" , b);
}

return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something? Anybody able to give me pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You use `n` in calculations before it's initialized. Order matters!

Comment: @muquit, I have seen that you have been accepting and unaccepting my answer a couple of times in the last few hours. Please, have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you can. Also, if you want some clarifications or further explanations do not hesitate to write comments or to **ask another question**! As mentioned, do not mind those downvotes, your question was absolutely legit and you expressed yourself politely. Everybody *deserves* to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because on the initialization you are doing an operation, but "n" hasn't got a value.
You have to put the operation "a=-n-4" before the printf function (when the variable "n" has a known value). That maybe solve your problem, because on the beginning the variable "n" has not a value (TRASH VALUE), so "a" has not a value (TRASH VALUE).
As I said, try to put the math operation after the scanf function and tell me if it works.

On the other hand, the contidion of your "else":

> if (n >= 3 || n <= 10)

the condition of "n<=10" has no sense, because all value lower than 10 are higher than 3.

BR.

Comment: The "contidion" part of your answer refers to wrong comparison not making sense, it is the `n >= 3` that does not make sense, except for clarity... Also these questions are categorized in the "typo" category, there is not much use for future learners from these, as you cannot really find this question using a search engine for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not **initialise** variables yourself, in **C**, they will not be auto-initialised (unless they are either `static`/`global` variables).

What happens when you do this:

`int a`;

Is that a memory address block of `sizeof(int)` is **reserved** to this variable name, but nothing is actually written by the assigned address... That means that whatever was contained at that memory address is not "wiped" or given any value.

So it is very **likely** that something was already written at that address, and you are just reading some *junk* value that it was already stored at that memory address.

Pretty much like choosing a piece of paper of the size that you need, on which **you will write something**, from a bunch of leftover magazines and newspapers. Maybe you would like to do your math homework on that piece of paper, but if you try reading what's actually written on there, before your write anything on it, you'll find nothing but outdates news!

**Experiment with this block of code:**

```c
int main()
{

   int n;

   printf("Non-initialised n value: %d\n", n);

   int a = n + 1;

   printf("Value of n incremented by one: %d\n", a);

   n = 4;

   printf("Value of initialised n:\n", n);
   
   return 0;

}
```

Is it clearer, now? You were reading the value of `n`, which was a rubbish value (*outdated football match results, maybe?*) and you were actually doing stuff on that garbage value, with: `int a = -n-4;`

So, now that you know this, you also know that you can fix your program by making sure that all the operations on `n` are carried out after `n` is given a proper value, so...

```c
int main()
{

   int n;

   printf("ENTER AN INTEGER: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   int a = -n - 4;
   int square = n * n;
   int b = square - 7;

   if (n < 3)
      printf("%d", a);

   else
   {
      if (n >= 3 || n <= 10)
         printf("%d", b);
   }
   return 0;
}
```